# Play two audio files on

Tags: twilio

I would like to use Twilio API the play two voice messages over the phone.

Something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Play>https://mysite/aaa.mp3</Play>
    <Play>https://mysite/bbb.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yup.  This is totally possible just as you have it.  The caller will hear `aaa.mp3` first, followed by `bbb.mp3`.

Hope that helps.